# x-axis and y-axis can't display data from APi in bar chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new using react. I want to connect my bar chart with the data I have in the table. When I click "Next/Previous" the table container data will change, so does in the bar chart. It succesfully change in the table. But, in the bar chart it failed to show the data from API in the x-axis and y-axis. Check my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cohen-zsojb?file=/src/App.js
Hope anyone can help me

Thank You

Comment: Is it intentionally that you have  let mass_arr = []; in line 32 and at the same time a constant called exactly the same in line 12 (same for height_arr and name_arr)?

Comment: oh sorry I multiple declare it, I already update in code

Comment: what browser are you using? every time I click the Next button in Chrome (also on Firefox) I get the following error in the console "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codesandbox.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS"

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but it work fine in my local. I already using https

Comment: Strange, somehow (I think it's Axios) the url gets changed from https to http

Comment: What should I do then?